# Is it possible to create SharePoint Office 365 document discussion categories rather than individual questions in a discussion repo?

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

I would like to categorize "discussions" in SharePoint discussions - similar to forum categories. Is there way to do so, rather than have one discussion board with many questions?

I have downloaded and installed the [2010 Discussions List Template](http://365.webbrewers.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=55), but it appears that only provides a default *threaded view*.

Are there other discussion templates or options to accomplish this in SharePoint?